# Onclick load page in Div and change text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this button and what it currently does is onclick it changes the text from `text1` to `text2` Below is the button and the script which achieves this.

**Button**

```
<button type="button" id="buttonsend" style="margin-top:-7px;" class="btn btn-default">
   <span>text 1</span>
   <span style="display:none">text 2</span>
</button>

<div id="load"></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('#buttonsend').click(function() {
    $('span',this).toggle();
});
```

What I want it to also do is load a page in the `#load` div only once its clicked and also refresh the page loaded in the div every 10 seconds.

**Example**

Once the button is clicked the text is changed to `text2` and the `#load` div loads the demo.html page and refreshes this page every 10 seconds. once the button is clicked again the `#load` div stops refreshing the page and the text returns to `text1`. I'm really sorry for making this almost a request but I'm having some difficulties achieving this.

I have coded this script below which refreshes a page loaded in a div every 10 seconds however it loads before the button is clicked so I'm not sure how to get it work once the button is clicked and when the button is clicked again to stop refreshing. Thankyou.

**Refresh Script**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
       $("#load").load('/demo.html')
    }, 10000);
});
```

Comment: The Intervall is in ms, you'd need to enter 10,000 for 10s :)

Comment: @AlexG eagle eyed :3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a boolean variable for this, which you toggle when the button is clicked, and in your interval callback you just check whether it is set before reloading:

```
var reload = false;
$('#buttonsend').click(function() {
    reload = !reload;
    // other actions...
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
        if (reload) $("#load").load('/demo.html')
    }, 1000); // or 10000 if you want 10 sec.
});
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was after thank-you so much for the clean fast response really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using variables to keep the state of your button:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var button_state = 'state1';

  function toggleButtonState() {
    if(button_state == 'state1') button_state == 'state2';
    else button_state == 'state1';
  }

  $('#buttonsend').click(function() {
    toggleButtonState();
    $('span',this).toggle();
  });

  setInterval(function(){
    if(button_state == 'state2') $("#load").load('/demo.html');
  }, 10000);
});
```

Comment: Thankyou for the answer will defiantly +1 it will have to mark the other answer as the answer though beat you too it :3 aha thankyou though really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

While Wikiti's and trincot's answers are correct, I believe it's better to disable the loop while it's not used, using `clearInterval`. This will make sure that content will load the moment when user presses the button - otherwise, like in Wikiti's and trincot's answers, user may miss the loop iteration and click the button when there are 9 seconds to the next iteration, so he will have to wait 9 seconds for the content to begin loading.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var timer = "none";

  function startLoop() {
    timer = setInterval(function(){
      $("#load").load('/demo.html');
    }, 10000);
  }

  function toggleButtonState() {
    if (timer === "none") { startLoop(); }
    else { clearInterval(timer); timer = "none"; }
  }

  $('#buttonsend').click(function() {
    toggleButtonState();
    $('span',this).toggle();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you give text2 and id you can see if it is visible or not, or wrap it in a div, I had a similar need to have a countdown and to pause when the div was visible. Can't remember where I took the below from. Basically counts down from 300, but pauses when the div called 'callUpdateWrap' is visible. I also had it update a timer on the page itself (see way down the page):

JS:

```
 function refreshpage(interval, countdownel, totalel){
    var countdownel = document.getElementById(countdownel)
    var totalel = document.getElementById(totalel)
    var timeleft = interval+1
    var countdowntimer

    function countdown(){
        if (!$('#callUpdateWrap').is(':visible')) {
        timeleft--
        }
        countdownel.innerHTML = timeleft
        if (timeleft == 0){
            clearTimeout(countdowntimer)
            window.location.reload()
        }
        countdowntimer = setTimeout(function(){
            countdown()
        }, 1000)

    }

    countdown()
    }

    window.onload = function(){
        refreshpage(300, "countdown") // refreshpage(duration_in_seconds, id_of_element_to_show_result)
    }
```

HTML:

```
<h2>Page will Refresh in <b id="countdown"></b> seconds</h2>
```

Quick Edit: 
If you need the timer to reset, where the div is checked if visible, you could add an else to set the time back to 10.